# How to render multiple html lists with AppScrip?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am new to the world of * AppScript * I am currently designing a ** WepApp ** which is made up of html lists that connect to Mysql, when I individually test my lists paint correctly and their icons modify and update the data, without However ** the problem is ** when I join all my lists and call them through their corresponding url only the last one paints me the others are blank. For example of 10 lists I call # 2 the log tells me to call 10; I call 5 the same thing happens and if I call 10 it paints the data and they are allowed to be modified.
Within what I have searched I find that my problem lies in the way I render my pages but I cannot find the right path, so I ask for your support.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template ;
  var view = e.parameters.v;

  if(view == null){
    template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index");
  }if(view == "Index"){
    template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index");
  }if(view != null && view != "Index"){
    template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(view);
  }

  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Documental')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);


}

function getTemplate(view){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(view);
}
```

and with this JavaScript method I connect my appscript code to pass it to my html

```
window.onload = function () {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(run_This_On_Success)
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .readAreaPRE();
};
function onFailure(error) {
  var div = document.getElementById("output");
  div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
}
function run_This_On_Success (readAreaPRE) {

  let table = $("#selectTable");
  table.find("tbody tr").remove();
  table.append("<tr><td>" + "</td><td>" + "</td></tr>");

  readAreaPRE.forEach(function (e1, readAreaPRE) {    
    table.append(
      "<tr><td>" +
        e1[0] +
        "</td><td>" +
        e1[1] +
        "</td><td>" +
        "<p><a class='modal-trigger' id=" + e1[0] + " href='#modal1' onclick='capturaid("+e1[0]+",&#39;"+ e1[1]+"&#39;)'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></a>" +
        "<a class='modal-trigger' href='#modal3' onclick='capturaidsup("+e1[0]+")'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></a></p>" +
        "</td></tr>"
    );
  });
};


  function capturaidsup(dato1){  
 $("#delAreaPRE").val(dato1)
 }

 function capturaid(item1,item2) {
  $("#uptAreaPRE1").val(item1);
  $("#uptAreaPRE2").val(item2);


}
```

here is my function: *readArePRE*

```
function readAreaPRE() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(url, user, contra);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery(
    "CALL `BD_CENDOC_COL`.`sp_lee_tb_ref_AreasPRE`()"
  );
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  var rowString = new Array(results.length);
  var i = 0;
  while (results.next()) {
    var id_areaPRE = results.getInt("id_areaPRE");
    var AreaPRE = results.getString("AreaPRE");

    rowString[i] = new Array(numCols);
    rowString[i][0] = id_areaPRE;
    rowString[i][1] = AreaPRE;
    i++;
  }
  return rowString;
  conn.close();
  results.close();
}
```

Thank you in advance, any correction to ask my question will be welcome.

Comment: I don't understand your code. Where is the function `readAreaPRE` also, you are also using what is supposed to be a function (`readAreaPRE`) this doesn't make much sense. Where are you actually querying your database?
Also in the `forEach` you also use the variable name `readAreaPRE` to refer to the index. Overall, this seems quite confusing, could you maybe share the error you are getting and explain a little bit your code?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Raserhin, I search with my code is from my Mysql database is to show each table in a different html in the most optimal way, because there are many tables, here is my function:

Comment: Could you maybe share what is the error message you are getting, where is the line failing. Also you have lines of code after a `return` statement that will never be executed.